# vb.net - Read Xml web response

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, web, response

I need to read the some values from a response web page in vb.net

When i go to the url= 192.168.1.254/?custom=1&cmd=3014
i get this response:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Function>
<Cmd>2002</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2003</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2004</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2006</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2007</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>2008</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2010</Cmd>
<Status>3</Status>
<Cmd>1004</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>1002</Cmd>
<Status>4</Status>
<Cmd>1005</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>1006</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>1007</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>1008</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>1009</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>2005</Cmd>
<Status>6</Status>
<Cmd>1011</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>3025</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>3026</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>3011</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>3010</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>3007</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
<Cmd>3003</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>3004</Cmd>
<Status>1</Status>
<Cmd>3008</Cmd>
<Status>0</Status>
</Function>
```

I need a way to get the cmd id and the value. So i can know the status of the single functions.

Ex:

3003 - 0 i'll know that the function Rotate is off
3004 - 1 i'll know that the function Date is on
3008 - 4 i'll know what resolution is using

Etc etc.

How can i do that ?

Comment: What have you tried?  What part do you need help with - making the web request, parsing the XML, both?

Comment: I'd say both. Since i make my web request using Webbrowser.navigate(URL) and i'm sure isn't the best way to do it.. :/

Comment: Do you just want to get the data from the URL to parse into Cmd and Status info?  i.e. Do you really need the web browser control, or was that just your first attempt at downloading data from the web server?  If you just want the XML string as data, something like [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be an option, then you could use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to parse the XML.

Comment: I don't think i need the web browser control. it was just myfirst attempt. Ok, i think i need to explain something better.

The web server is from an action cam and i'm trying to make a Pc application to  control it.
All the functions are controlled by a get request to the cam url.To set something i just need to visit the url, making a get request.
Ex to set a different resolution i just need to visit url= 192.168.1.254/?custom=1&cmd=2002&par=1 (par 1-4 for diff res)
Visiting url= 192.168.1.254/?custom=1&cmd=3014 i get the current settings.That's why i need to retrieve them individually.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers to get you started.  This shows how to download the XML from the server as a string and then parse it, using LINQ to XML, into a list of anonymous types.  You'll need to work out the appropriate imports and options (`Option Infer On` is probably required).  You can use the same `DownloadString` method to make other `GET` requests to the server.  You may want to look at [`WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138332%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if this is in some sort of UI, to avoid blocking.

```vb
' Download the XML from the server
Dim wc = New WebClient()
Dim xmlString As String = wc.DownloadString("http://192.168.1.254/?custom=1&cmd=3014")

' Parse the XML into something more usable
Dim xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString)
Dim cmdStatus =
    From c In xml...<Cmd>
    Let s = DirectCast(c.NextNode, XElement)
    Select Cmd = c.Value, Status = s.Value

' Dump the value to the console - not sure what you want to do here
For Each cs In cmdStatus
    Console.WriteLine("Cmd: {0}, Status: {1}", cs.Cmd, cs.Status)
Next
```

Comment: This is working absolutely great !! Thank you.. (:
Now i just need to figure it out how to store them, store the changes if applied and print everything on a text box or something more readable. (like swapping the cmd id with the cmd name and stuff)
Thank you for the help Mark !!! ;)